# How to check if ARCore lib/apk installed on device?

Tags: java, android, arcore

If I understand well, once ARCore 1.0 will be released on Google Play, it will be necessary to install it on the device in order to be able to run an ARCore app.

How to check if ARCore lib/apk is installed on device ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be sufficient to do something like:

```
    try {
        arCoreSession = Session(this)

        val config = Config(arCoreSession)
        if (!arCoreSession.isSupported(config)) {
            Logger.d("ARCore not installed")
        } else {
            arCoreSession.configure(config)
        }
    } catch (ex: Throwable) {
        Logger.d("ARCore not installed")
    }
```

This is what I'm using here for one my apps and works fine on devices with or wothout ARCore.

Comment: This is an old approach. Should be done with `ArCoreApk.getInstance().checkAvailability(this)` now.

Comment: @soshial Can you please add your comment to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75130627/how-to-know-if-a-given-device-is-in-the-list-of-supported-devices-for-ar) issue? It will be very helpful for me since I am struggling a lot with this stuff.

Answer (score 3):

According to [ARCore documentation 1.4.0](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/enable-arcore#runtime), if optional it is important check its availability recursively and then install it:

```
void maybeEnableArButton() {
  // Likely called from Activity.onCreate() of an activity with AR buttons.
  ArCoreApk.Availability availability = ArCoreApk.getInstance().checkAvailability(this);
  if (availability.isTransient()) {
    // re-query at 5Hz while we check compatibility.
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        maybeEnableArButton();
      }
    }, 200);
  }
  if (availability.isSupported()) {
    mArButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mArButton.setEnabled(true);
    // indicator on the button.
  } else { // unsupported or unknown
    mArButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    mArButton.setEnabled(false);
  }
}
```

If already supported just check if ARCore is installed:

```
// Set to true ensures requestInstall() triggers installation if necessary.
private boolean mUserRequestedInstall = true;

// in onResume:
try {
  if (mSession == null) {
    switch (ArCoreApk.getInstance().requestInstall(this, mUserRequestedInstall)) {
      case INSTALLED:
        mSession = new Session(this);
        // Success.
        break;
      case INSTALL_REQUESTED:
        // Ensures next invocation of requestInstall() will either return
        // INSTALLED or throw an exception.
        mUserRequestedInstall = false;
        return;
    }
  }
} catch (UnavailableUserDeclinedInstallationException e) {
  // Display an appropriate message to the user and return gracefully.
  return;
} catch (...) {  // current catch statements
  ...
  return;  // mSession is still null
}
```

Comment: This method is giving false positives.https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/issues/716

Comment: Time has passed since my post, right now I would create a dedicated class named `Permission` with static methods as the now updated section [Request camera permission (AR Optional and AR Required apps)](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/enable-arcore#request_camera_permission_ar_optional_and_ar_required_apps) of ARCore documentation 1.7.0 states. In there, also a link to an example github class is given.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it is easier to request this with Rx methodology. Here's the code:

```
private fun getArAvailabilityRx(context: Context): Single<ArCoreApk.Availability> {
    return Single.fromCallable<ArCoreApk.Availability> {
        ArCoreApk.getInstance().checkAvailability(context)
    }.flatMap { availability ->
        if (availability.isTransient) {
            // `isTransient` means it hasn't finished loading value; let's request the value in 500 ms
            getArAvailabilityRx(context).delaySubscription(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        } else {
            Single.just(availability)
        }
    }.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
}
```

Comment: how to use this function can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little utility class I wrote (based originally on something from https://github.com/google/helloargdx).

It will perform all the checks and setup necessary, in order to ensure it is safe to launch a `Session`.

```
abstract class ArCheckFragment : Fragment() {

    private var userRequestedInstall = true

    abstract fun onCameraPermissionDeny()

    abstract fun onArCoreUnavailable(availability: Availability)

    abstract fun onArCoreInstallFail(exception: UnavailableException)

    abstract fun onArCoreInstallSuccess()

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        performCheck()
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA_PERMISSION) {
            for (i in permissions.indices) {
                if (permissions[i] == Manifest.permission.CAMERA &&
                    grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                ) {
                    checkArCore()
                    return
                }
            }
            onCameraPermissionDeny()
        }
    }

    /**
     * Performs the whole check
     */
    fun performCheck() {
        if (requestCameraPermission()) {
            checkArCore()
        }
    }

    /**
     * Requests the camera permission, if necessary.
     * @return whether camera permission is already granted. If so, the permission won't be requested.
     */
    private fun requestCameraPermission(): Boolean {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                requireContext(),
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA
            ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            return true
        }
        requestPermissions(arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA), REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA_PERMISSION)
        return false
    }

    private fun checkArCore() {
        if (!isResumed) {
            return
        }
        val availability = ArCoreApk.getInstance().checkAvailability(activity)
        if (availability.isTransient) {
            requireView().postDelayed(AR_CORE_CHECK_INTERVAL) { checkArCore() }
            return
        }
        when (availability) {
            Availability.SUPPORTED_INSTALLED ->
                onArCoreInstallSuccess()
            Availability.SUPPORTED_APK_TOO_OLD,
            Availability.SUPPORTED_NOT_INSTALLED ->
                startArCoreInstallation()
            else ->
                onArCoreUnavailable(availability)
        }
    }

    private fun startArCoreInstallation() {
        try {
            val installStatus =
                ArCoreApk.getInstance().requestInstall(activity, userRequestedInstall)
            when (installStatus) {
                InstallStatus.INSTALLED -> onArCoreInstallSuccess()
                InstallStatus.INSTALL_REQUESTED,
                null ->
                    // Ensures next invocation of requestInstall() will either return
                    // INSTALLED or throw an exception.
                    userRequestedInstall = false
            }
        } catch (exception: UnavailableException) {
            onArCoreInstallFail(exception)
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private const val REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA_PERMISSION = 1
        private const val AR_CORE_CHECK_INTERVAL = 200L
    }
}
```

You can subclass this Fragment and implement the abstract functions to receive callbacks on what the result of these checks is. Only in `onArCoreInstallSuccess` is it safe to create a `Session`.