# How to know if a given device is in the list of supported devices for ARCore?

Tags: android, react-native, augmented-reality, arcore

I am using [Google CoreAR package](https://developers.google.com/ar) in my `React-Native` app for AR support. There are some devices which support AR and some not. I am getting error while I run the application in non-supported devices. I want to render a message instead showing error on the screen. For this `Google CoreAR` package is providing the [solution](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/enable-arcore#java) which is not working for me.

```java
void maybeEnableArButton() {
  ArCoreApk.Availability availability = ArCoreApk.getInstance().checkAvailability(this);
  if (availability.isTransient()) {
    // Continue to query availability at 5Hz while compatibility is checked in the background.
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        maybeEnableArButton();
      }
    }, 200);
  }
  if (availability.isSupported()) {
    mArButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mArButton.setEnabled(true);
  } else { // The device is unsupported or unknown.
    mArButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    mArButton.setEnabled(false);
  }
}
```

The problem with above code snippet is that `availability.isSupported()` is always returning `true` and that's why else part of code is not running. Can you guys please help me with this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution for this problem. `ArCoreApk.Availability` has some methods which can be used. You can find these methods in the
[documentation](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/com/google/ar/core/ArCoreApk.Availability). The method `ArCoreApk.Availability`
return either `SUPPORTED_INSTALLED` or `SUPPORTED_NOT_INSTALLED` depending on device support. So based on this return value we can do the stuff.

I did like this.

```java
@ReactMethod
  public ArCoreApk.Availability getSupport(){

    ArCoreApk.Availability availability = ArCoreApk.getInstance().checkAvailability(this.getReactApplicationContext());

    return availability.name();
  }
```